Joint PMF to marginal PMF
Consider X and Y as rvs and joint PMF $p_{X,Y}(x, y)$.
As I understood we can always get $p_X(x)$ and $p_Y(y)$ by taking marginal PMF, it doesn't matter whether it dependent or not.
As I also understand we can't get joint PMF back from marginal PMF ($p_X(x)$ and $p_Y(y)$. Because in both cases (dependent/independent) computation of $p_{X, Y}(x, y)$ is different. But then I can't understand why taking marginal always yields $p_X(x)$ and $p_Y(y)$?

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables, their joint distribution is obtained by specifying $P(X=x, Y=y)$ for every possible value of $x$ and $y$. Now given the joint distribution, you can deduce $P(X=x)$ for any $x$ by first writing the event $\{X=x\}$ as the disjoint union of events $\{X=x, Y=y\}$ where the union is taken over all possible values $y$:
$$\{X=x\} = \bigcup_y \{X=x, Y=y\}$$ And since the probability of a disjoint union of events is the sum of the individual event probabilities, this means:
$$P(X=x)=\sum_y P(X=x, Y=y).$$ But this last equation can be written
$$p_X(x) = \sum_y p_{X,Y}(x,y),$$ which is exactly how you obtain the marginal PMF for $X$ from the joint PMF of $X$ and $Y$.
A similar argument shows that you can deduce the marginal PMF of $Y$ from the joint PMF.

Marginalization will always produce a marginal measure, because ... that is what it means.
By definition the marginal probability mass function for a random variable is the accumulation of the joint probability mass functions over all supported outcomes where that random variable is a given value.   This is the Law of Total Probability.
$$\begin{align}p_{\small X}(x):=\sum_t p_{\small X,Y}(x,t)\\p_{\small Y}(y):=\sum_s p_{\small X,Y}(s,y) \end{align}$$
